# Stuck with detecting next line from console

Tags: java

I am banging my head to the wall but just can't figure out what is going wrong. Simple program but not working. I need to get 3 inputs(integers) from user. End the program on either array full or when user presses enter. Here is what i am trying without any luck. It works fine all the situtations EXCEPT it cant detect nextline.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] intArray = new int[3];
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("Start!!");
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter int");
        if (sc.hasNextInt() && counter <= 2) {
            intArray[counter] = sc.nextInt();
            counter++;

        } else {
            if (counter >= 3) {
                System.out.println("Array is full");
                System.out.println("Array ELemnets : " + Arrays.toString(intArray));
                break;
            }
            if (sc.next().isEmpty() || sc.next().equals("\n")){
                System.out.println("Its empty");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("wrong input.");
            }
        }

    }
    sc.close();
```

Please help me . Why is it not detecting next line. I have googled already and tried lot of solutions provided but none worked for me. Any HELP!!!
Thanks 
Edited code :
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int[] intArray = new int[3];
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("Start!!");
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter int");
        if (sc.hasNextInt() && counter <= 2) {
            intArray[counter] = sc.nextInt();
            counter++;

        } else {
            if (counter >= 3) {
                System.out.println("Array is full");
                System.out.println("Array ELemnets : " + Arrays.toString(intArray));
                break;
            }
            String next = sc.next();
            if (next.isEmpty() || next.equals("\n"))

            {
                System.out.println("Its empty");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("wrong input.");
            }
        }

    }
    sc.close();

}
```

Comment: You call `sc.next()` twice in your if-statement, so you're reading two *separate* characters and testing things on them.

Comment: Agreed, assign the scanner's value to a variable and then test that in your condition: `String next = sc.next(); if (next.isBlank() || next.equals("\n")) { //etc...`

Comment: Agree it was wrong. I edited the code but still same. Even when i debug the code , it just doesnt come to else part.It just hangs and doesn't do anything

Comment: Interesting, mine appeared to run fine when I added a 4th element to the array; it printed: *"Array is full
Array ELemnets : [56, 78, 13]"* and the program exited. **Edit:** Nevermind, it does hang; I was looking at the wrong portion of the else block.

Comment: Newlines (`\n`) don't get delivered by a`Scanner `, it just reads on and delivers the next int on the next line. If you want to handle this by line, add a new scanner for each line.

Comment: Change `sc.hasNextInt` to `sc.hasNextLine` and `sc.nextInt` to `sc.nextLine`. Then compare the whole line with "\n" or parse it with `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: @daniu How can i add new scanner for new line?

Comment: @Jeena I tried out what I had in mind and it didn't work; looks like for a `Scanner`, you only get values at all after return has been pressed. You probably have to resort to reading the input differently.

Comment: yaah it seems so. Both  the solution given below are working fine. It seems there is no other way to do it than to get the String and then parse it. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int[] intArray = new int[3];
    int counter = 0;
    boolean enterPressed = false; // added boolean to test if they entered a blank line

    try (
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // declaring in a try-with-resources, so it automatically closes.
        ) {

        System.out.println("Start!!");
        System.out.println("Enter int"); // Have to print this the first time
        while (counter < 3 && !enterPressed) {
            if (counter > 0) { System.out.println("Enter int"); }
            String next = sc.nextLine(); // just grab a line (the user pressed enter)
            if (next.isEmpty()) {
                enterPressed = true;
            } else {
                try {
                    intArray[counter] = Integer.parseInt(next);
                    counter++;
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    System.out.println("wrong input.");
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But what is the problem with my code. Why is it not looking and the when I press enter?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is sticking because it's waiting on the conditional check for `sc.hasNextInt()`. The solution I propose below, manually parses the user-input string to see if it's an int, rather than using the Scanner's functionality to check if it's an int or not.

I left some comments in the code to hopefully add clarity. Let me know if anything doesn't make sense, and I'm happy to elaborate!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTestNew {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] intArray = new int[3];
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.println("Start!!");

        // Variable used to hold the user's input via the Scanner.
        String userInput = null;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            userInput = sc.nextLine();

            // Check to see if an empty string/enter/return has been input:
            if (userInput.length() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Input is empty!");
                break;
            }

            // Checking to see if the input can be parsed into an int. If it can't, retry.
            int intInput = 0;
            try {
                intInput = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input for type Integer. Please try again.");
                continue;
            }

            // We know we have an int at this point. Checking that the array isn't already
            // filled.
            if (counter <= 2) {
                intArray[counter] = intInput;
                counter++;

                // The array is filled, act accordingly.
            } else if (counter > 2) {
                System.out.println("Array is full.");
                System.out.printf("Array Elements: %s", Arrays.toString(intArray));
                break;
            }
            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```